# Wrong behaviour for CircuitBreaker in Micronaut

Tags: micronaut, rx-java3

Have a controller:

```
@Controller
@CircuitBreaker
public class ExampleController {

    @Get("/")
    public Single<String> endpoint() {
        return Single.fromSupplier(this::serviceCall);
    }

    private String serviceCall() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Fist call works absolutely fine. However, second call won't fail with the same exception, if happens when CircuitBreaker is open. Instead, it will case CircuitOpenException in micronaut infrastructure that will result in broken request.

Is any workaround for that issue?

Full example: https://github.com/artfable/micronaut-test

**Update:**

Created an issue: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-rxjava3/issues/87

Annotation works fine with Single from rxjava2. So, as a workaround, use service that will have the annotation and return rxjava2 Single, convert to rxjava3 Single in a controller.

Comment: What is the desired behavior?

Comment: FYI... I asked that question in Gitter and Artems response was "same exception, http status code, response body as was in the first one, but without executing code in the controller."

Comment: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-rxjava3/issues/87